# for loop over list ignores second element?

Tags: python

I have a very strange bug and I can't see where I go wrong. I want to loop over a list of objects

```
objects =  [<object 1>, <object 2>, <object 3>, <object 4>, <Query_Category 5>, <object 6>]
```

and I do a simple

```
for i, object in enumerate(objects):
    print "delete ", object
    objects.pop(i)
```

and the output is

```
delete  <Query_Category 1>
delete  <Query_Category 3>
delete  <Query_Category 4>
delete  <Query_Category 5>
delete  <Query_Category 6>
```

so the loop ignored the second element? This result is reproducible, meaning if I run it again it leads to the same outcome??? 
This is probably not reproducible for you, since I guess this is caused by something strange in my code??? But I have no idea what to look for?
Is there sum fundamental python principle I am missing here?
thanks
carl

Comment: Modifying the object that you're iterating over is almost never a good idea. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 5):

Do not modify container you are iterating over inside the loop. Due to pop operation your container changes and thus - iteration over it fails (skips an element).

If you just want to iterate over collection and destroy it at the end - pop from it till it is not empty

```
a = range(10)

while len(a):
  print a.pop(0)
```

gives

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

as expected.

Thus in your case

```
while len(objects):
    object = objects.pop(0)
    print "delete ", object
```